# ExtJS 4.2 fieldset Layout Behavior (Width not shrinking)

Tags: extjs, extjs4

This might be a general question in regards to ExtJS 4.2 tabpanel forms.

On the form I have multiple dropdown comboboxes, and they're grouped into fieldset items.

The issue I'm having is when I resize the browser window, the fieldsets only resize one way: when the browser is made wider.

So for example, if I expand the browser to make it a little wider, the fieldset resizes perfectly to fit within the browser. However if I make the browser smaller (width-wise), the fieldset remains the same, and scrollbars will appear.

I have the fieldset config values set to:

```
xtype: 'fieldset',
title: 'Group 1',
layout: 'anchor',
defaults: { anchor: '-20' },
....
```

I have the same form set up on a server running extJS 4.0 and I do not have this issue, the fieldset resizes fine when the browser size is changed in any way.

Is there a new config I missed in extJS 4.2?

Answer (score 0):

Disregard my question, I figured it out.  I had the main layout set to 'form', and I just needed to change it to 'anchor' as well.